# Pixel index out of range

Tags: python, pygame

good afternoon, i would like to ask a question about this error i´m getting in my game. Im doing a simple game in pygame but i cant discover why i´m having this error. i will print the  relevant code:

```
bottomX=-1000  
bottomY=300


FishList = [] 
NumFish=0

while NumFish<20:
    xfish=random.randrange(5,2550) 
    yfish=random.randrange(20,150) 

    IsInWater=(bottom.get_at([xFish+5,yFish+7])== (80,86,210,255))
    if IsInWater: 
        FishList.append([xFish,yFish])

    NumFish= NumFish + 1
```

```
for i in range(len(FishList)):
        [xFish,yFish] = FishList[i]

        mXp = random.randrange(-5,5) #Move in X
        mYp = random.randrange(-5,6) #Move in y

        FishStillInWater = (xFish+mXp+5>0 and xFish+mXp+5<3000 and yFish+mYp+7>10 and yFish+mYp+7 < 200 and (fundo.get_at([xFish+mXp+5,yFish+mYp+7])== (80,86,210,255))) 
        if FishStillInWater:
        # If in water, moves
            FishList[i][0] = xFish + mXp
            FishList[i][1] = yGish + mYp
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,red,[bottomX + FishList[i][0],300 + FishList[i][1],15,10],0)




        for x in range(-7,7):
            for y in range(-5,5):
                FishDies=screen.get_at([bottomX + FishList[i][0]+x,300 + FishList[i][1]+y])==(0,0,0,255)# 0,0,0,255 is the color of the "bullets"
                if FishDies:
                    yFish = 10000
                    points= points + 5
```

The error is:

FishDies=screen.get_at([bottomX + FishList[i][0]+x,300 + FishList[i][1]+y])==(0,0,0,255)
IndexError: pixel index out of range

Thx for your time guys, hope you can help me, if u need any thing else to understand the code tell me plz

Comment: If you add `print [bottomX + FishList[i][0]+x,300 + FishList[i][1]+y]` just above the line that's causing the error, you shoud be able to get some insight on why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down a bit.

The error is saying, that you want to access a pixel, that is not on the surface. Here are your calculations:

The smallest possible fish coordinates are the following: (5,20), while the biggest are (2550,150).

You then want to check for the color of the pixel, but the fish might have moved off the screen, or only a part of it have moved.

I would recommend a normal `collide_rect` to check for collisions with bullets. There are many example on how to do this.

Comment: Humm ic, im still new to pygame, could u make an exemple please?

Comment: There are far too many examples on the web, showing exactly how to check for collision. Try to implement it, and if you have any problems, post a new question.